# Parse text using substring in mysql

Tags: mysql, parsing

I want to parse a text using substring. The format we have for the text is like this:

```
N, Adele, A, 18
```

And the substring we do is like this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ',', 2), ', ', -1) as 'Name', 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ',', 4), ', ', -1) as 'Age',
```

The output we get is:

```
|   Name    |   Age |
|   Adele   |   18  |
```

But we want to change the text format to:

```
N Adele, A 18
```

What would be the correct syntax so can I parse the text in the position 1 (N Adele) and use the delimiter space and just get Adele? And then same for the next text (A 18)?

I tried doing

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, ' ', 1), ', ', -1) as 'Name',
```

But the output I got is just

```
|   Name    |
|   N       |
```

The output I was hoping for is like this:

```
|   Name    |
|   Adele   |
```

Comment: What is the desired output that you're after? Is it `N Adele, A 18` or is it the same as the output you're already getting? I'm unsure.

Comment: @scrowler On the text `N Adele, A 18` I want to get the output `Adele` and `18`

Comment: Yes that's just field names and is not important. On the text `N Adele` I just want to get the `Adele` part of that text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming here that you want to change your original data structure and still be able to get the results out. You change your data structure to:

```
N Adele, A 18 -- etc
```

With the potential to have multiple names as the name (space separated), my previous example is not correct.

You could trim off the `N` and `A` directly with their space, knowing that they will only ever be two characters long and that they will always be there, like this:

```
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, ',', 1)), 3) AS 'Name',
SUBSTRING(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, ',', -1)), 3) AS 'Age'
```

To get:

```
Name   |   Age
--------------------
Adele  |   18
```

Comment: Ah wait, what if the text is like `N Adele Gaga` is it still going to give the output `Adele Gaga` ?

Comment: Use @leon's answer - his is better. I've added another example for you anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(text, 2, INSTR(text, ',') - INSTR(text, ' ')) AS Name,
  SUBSTRING(text, INSTR(text, ',') + 3, LENGTH(text) - INSTR(text, ',') + 3) AS Age
FROM your_table;
```

as the position of the field descriptors (`N` and `A`) are fixed (relative to the start of the string and to the comma). You can check the working query in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf159/1).